How to insert a regplot after a violinplot
When I try to combine a regplot and a violinplot, they are drawn at a different positions.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Magnitudes': magnitudes, 'Lengths': np.log10(lengths), 'Widths': np.log10(widths)})

# Colors for violins
palette = sns.color_palette("Set2", len(fullpaths))
sns.set_style("darkgrid", {"grid.color": ".6", "grid.linestyle": ":"})
# Crear gráficos de violín con regresión lineal y personalización de color
plt.figure()

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
sns.regplot(x='Magnitudes', y='Lengths', data=df,scatter_kws={"alpha" : 0.0})
sns.violinplot(x='Magnitudes', y='Lengths', data=df, palette=palette, alpha=0.5,hue='Magnitudes',legend=False)
plt.title('Violin Plot of Lengths vs Magnitude')
plt.xlabel('Magnitude')
plt.ylabel('Lengths')
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
sns.regplot(x='Magnitudes', y='Widths', data=df,scatter_kws={"alpha" : 0.0})
sns.violinplot(x='Magnitudes', y='Widths', data=df, palette=palette, alpha=0.5,hue='Magnitudes',legend=False)
plt.title('Violin Plot of Widths vs Magnitude')
plt.xlabel('Magnitude')
plt.ylabel('Widths')



Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

By default, seaborn draws categorical plots, such as violin plots (or boxplots, bar plots, ...) with a categorical x-axis. Internally, they are at positions 0, 1, 2, .... Since Seaborn 0.13, these functions accept a parameter native_scale=True, which positions the violins at their true numerical position (this only works for a numerical x-axis). If these positions aren't nicely incrementing with the same distance, the minimum distance between two violins is used as reference for their widths.
Here is an example, including dummy test data, and using matplotlib's "modern" object-oriented interface (strongly recommended when there is more than one subplot).
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create some dummy test data
magnitudes = np.repeat(np.arange(8.1, 9.3001, 0.1), 50)
unique_magnitudes = np.unique(magnitudes)
lengths = 10 ** np.random.normal(0.1, 1, size=len(magnitudes)).cumsum()
widths = 10 ** np.random.normal(0.1, 1, size=len(magnitudes)).cumsum()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Magnitudes': magnitudes, 'Lengths': np.log10(lengths), 'Widths': np.log10(widths)})

# Colors for violins
palette = sns.color_palette("Set2", len(unique_magnitudes))
sns.set_style("darkgrid", {"grid.color": ".6", "grid.linestyle": ":"})
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=2, figsize=(10, 7))

sns.regplot(x='Magnitudes', y='Lengths', data=df, scatter_kws={"alpha": 0.0}, ax=ax1)
sns.violinplot(x='Magnitudes', y='Lengths', data=df, palette=palette, alpha=0.5, hue='Magnitudes', legend=False,
               native_scale=True, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('Violin Plot of Lengths vs Magnitude')
ax1.set_xticks(unique_magnitudes)  # make sure each x-position is labeled

sns.regplot(x='Magnitudes', y='Widths', data=df, scatter_kws={"alpha": 0.0}, ax=ax2)
sns.violinplot(x='Magnitudes', y='Widths', data=df, palette=palette, alpha=0.5, hue='Magnitudes', legend=False,
               native_scale=True, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('Violin Plot of Widths vs Magnitude')
ax2.set_xticks(unique_magnitudes)

plt.tight_layout()  # spacing for titles and labels
plt.show()


